# CDI Injection into existing object instance - worked with CDI 1.0 but not with CDI 1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

Due to limitations of a framework I have to use, I need to inject into existing object instances (can't created them as usual via CDI itself). My injection points are marked either with `@EJB` or `@Inject`.

With JBoss EAP 6.4, Java EE 6 and CDI 1.0 this worked perfectly fine with the following code:

```
public class DispatcherUtils {

    public static <T> void inject(T anObject) {
        BeanManager beanManager = getBeanManager();
        Class<T> objClass = (Class<T>) anObject.getClass();
        AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(objClass);
        InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
        CreationalContext<T> context = new IgnorantCreationalContext<>();
        injectionTarget.inject(anObject, context);
        injectionTarget.postConstruct(anObject);
    }

    private static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
        try {
            return (BeanManager) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        } catch (final NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

If I try to do the same in JBoss EAP 7.0, Java EE 7 and CDI 1.1 only injection points marked with `@Inject` are injected into the target objects, those marked with `@EJB` are not injected (their value remains null).

I do not understand why that is.

Is there any way to inject into existing objects with JBoss EAP 7.0, Java EE 7 and CDI 1.1 and have `@EJB` injection points populated as well?

---

Update, 2016-06-19, 20:11

I just discovered that the above pattern works as long as the object I want to inject into has a no-arg constructor.

Example - this **works**:

```
public class ExampleBean {

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    @Inject
    private SomeCdiBean someCdiBean;

    @EJB
    private SomeEjbService someEjbService;

    public ExampleBean() {
    }

    public ExampleBean(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

}
```

while this **does not work**:

```
public class ExampleBean {

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    @Inject
    private SomeCdiBean someCdiBean;

    @EJB
    private SomeEjbService someEjbService;

    public ExampleBean(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

}
```

Why does CDI check for the presence of a default constructor in such a case? (Note: the bean is **not** created by CDI, so the constructor shouldn't make any difference)

Comment: What does your `IgnorantCreationalContext` look like? DeltaSpike has the same feature, and it works fine on Wildfly 10: https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L448 maybe you'd consider switching to that?

Comment: That's my the `IgnorantCreationalContext` https://gist.github.com/t3chris/36d627528b5d059a272afd4ed8ccd148

I've also tried with Deltaspike, but saw the same result `@Inject` works, but `@EJB` remains at null value.

Comment: @JohnAment: I've updated my original question. Do you see any way to make CDI ignore the lack of a default constructor?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that your issue is your creational context.  Does this give you any different result? `CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);` instead of instantiating your context.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion does not make any difference...
Do you have any idea what else I could do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem might be that your `ExampleBean` **without** no-args constructor is not considered a [managed bean](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_managed_beans). And an integrator (Wildfly, EAP, glassfish,...) can only provide EE resource injection (`@EJB` being EE resource injection) into `managed beans`.

Quoting from [Weld doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_injection_services):

> An integrator may wish to use InjectionServices to provide additional field or method injection over-and-above that provided by Weld. An integration into a Java EE environment may use InjectionServices to provide EE resource injection for managed beans.

To make `ExampleBean` a `managed bean` and not use no-args constructor, you need to declare a constructor annotated with `@Inject`.

Though I am just taking a wild guess here and cannot really be sure why you say it worked with EAP 6 and CDI 1.0.

And one more note just for the record - from my knowledge EAP 7 contains **CDI 1.2** (rather than 1.1).

Comment: What you say regarding ExampleBean, that it is not a managed bean, I totally agree.

However, so far we used to simply go that way cause it worked fine.

I would now seek for a solution which allows us to tell the CDI engine that it is fine to inject into an instance which does not look like a managed bean (just as it did in EAP 6.x). There should not be any problem, since we have created that bean properly beforehand.

Regarding CDI 1.2 you are of course right, my fault.